# Return database errors in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, azure-functions, pyodbc

I have a Python Azure function. In the code, I have a Connection timeout error exception from pyodbc connection.

```
def connection():
    username = ''
    server = ''
    password = ''
    database = ''
    connection= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    return connection
```

When the connection times out the code fails with a connection timeout error in the logs. But I need the function to return the error value instead of showing the error message in the logs. Is there any way to achieve this in Python? Currently, I am using a try-except statement.

```
 try:
     conn = connection()
     # .....
 except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:
     raise e
```

Edit:

Helper code:

```
def connection():
    username = ''
    server = ''
    password = ''
    database = ''
    connection= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    return conctn


def read_table(table, cnxn):
    conctn.timeout = 3
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM ' + table, cnxn)
    if df.empty:
        raise customerror
    return df
```

Main code:

```
try:
        conn = connection()
        df1 = read_table("table_name", conn)
        
    except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:
        return e
    except customerror as e:
        return e
    else:
    .....
```

When the connection times out, the main code fails with the below error.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name': ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired (0) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

When the query times out I do not want the code to fail with the above error message instead I want to exit/terminate the code with a custom time out error message.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? I don't follow

Comment: What do you mean "return the error"?  Errors are automatically bubbled up through your code until they are caught and handled, or the code crashes with an unhandled exception.  Your code catches then re-raises an error, which is equivalent to not doing the `try-except` at all.  So, something else is catching your error, or your code is crashing with an unhandled exception, or the "error" you speak of is actually a "warning" and not an "error" (Show us your logs).  What behaviour are o seeing, and what behaviour do you want?

Comment: Connection check is in separate helper function. I will call this helper function in the main code. When I execute the main code I want the exception from the helper function to be saved in a variable and the main code should return this variable(which has connection timed out error)

Comment: ***You*** have to do that.  Catch the exception with `except` and then populate whatever data structures you want, then the function you described would return something like `return (conn, e)`

Comment: Note: Check your parameter names.  In `read_table()` you take in `cnxn` and then try to reference `conctn`.  It helps to be consistent; you use `conn` in `connection()`, so, use it everywhere, don't have different names on every other line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing, vaguely, something like...

```
def connection():

    username = ''
    server = ''
    password = ''
    database = ''

    try:
        return (
            pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ password),
            None
        )
    except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:
        return (
            None,
            e
        )
```

Then, an operational error will never cause a crash, and your calling code can be something like...

```
    conn, e = connection()

    if e:
        # do something with the error
    else:
        # do something with the connection
```

Comment: When I am trying to call the function its giving me the below error.
tuple' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Comment: @SanjanaSanju - Update your question with the function you wrote, the code you used to call it, and the full stack trace or the error you get.

Comment: @SanjanaSanju Well, that's nothing like the answer I gave you...  So, I'm passing now, good luck.